# JPA запрос с Join

Tags: java, jpa

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос, в котором нужно получить информацию из двух таблиц по передающимся данным. На вход поступают названия cityFrom и cityTo

Сущности: Flight

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "flight")
public class Flight {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "flightDate")
private Date flightDate;

@ManyToOne
private City cityFrom;

@ManyToOne
private City cityTo;
```

Сущность City

```
@Data
@Entity

@Table(name = "spr_city")
public class City implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "nameCity")
private String nameCity;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select f from Flight f 
join f.cityFrom cf 
join f.cityYo ct 
where cf.nameCity = ? and ct.nameCity = ?
```